# Erro com CURLFile

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web, libcurl

Olá, pessoal. Estou com o seguinte código:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" value="POST">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){

 $ch = curl_init();
 $cfile = new CURLFile($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['type'], $_FILES['image']['name']);
 $data = array("myimage" => $cfile);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://meuhost/upload.php");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);

 if($response == true) {echo "Arquivo enviado";}
 else {echo "Erro: " . curl_error($ch);}
 
}
?>
```

Entretanto, está me retornando o seguinte erro.

```
Fatal error: Class 'CURLFile' not found in /var/www/protocolo/teste/cria.php on line 10
```

O que pode ser? O meu CURL está habilitado no servidor!

Comment: Você olhou isso no `phpinfo();` para verificar se está habilitado?

Comment: Sim. cURL support: enabled

Comment: Tenta colocar assim: `new \CurlFile( ` , senao faça o outro teste conforme esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22381678/6510304)